# Create a date counter variable starting with a particular date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a variable as:
`start_dt = 201901` which is basically Jan 2019

I have an initial data frame as:

```
month
0
1
2
3
4
```

I want to add a new column (date) to the dataframe where for month 0, the date is the `start_dt` - 1 month, and for subsequent months, the date is a month + 1 increment.

I want the resulting dataframe as:

```
month   date
0       12/1/2018
1       1/1/2019
2       2/1/2019
3       3/1/2019
4       4/1/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract `1` and add datetimes converted to month periods by [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html) and then output convert to timestamps by [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.to_timestamp.html):

```
start_dt = 201801
start_dt = pd.to_datetime(start_dt, format='%Y%m')

s = df['month'].sub(1).add(start_dt.to_period('m')).dt.to_timestamp()
print (s)
0   2017-12-01
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-02-01
3   2018-03-01
4   2018-04-01
Name: month, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or is possible convert column to month offsets with subtract `1` and add datetime:

```
s = df['month'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(months=x-1)).add(start_dt)
print (s)
0   2017-12-01
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-02-01
3   2018-03-01
4   2018-04-01
Name: month, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use the third-party library `dateutil` to increment a datetime by one month:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start_dt = '201801'
number_of_rows = 10

start_dt = datetime.strptime(start_dt, '%Y%m')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [start_dt+relativedelta(months=+n)
                            for n in range(-1, number_of_rows-1)]})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        date
0 2017-12-01
1 2018-01-01
2 2018-02-01
3 2018-03-01
4 2018-04-01
5 2018-05-01
6 2018-06-01
7 2018-07-01
8 2018-08-01
9 2018-09-01
```

As you can see, in each iteration of the `for` loop, the initial datetime is being incremented by the corresponding number (starting at `-1`) of the iteration.